# Calculate time to fraction by using python

Tags: python, time

my time format is `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

> start_time = 2014-12-04 08:10:32
>
> end_time = 2014-12-04 12:34:45

Here i want output like `diff_time = 4.24`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: So can not do your homework for you ! can you show what you try before ?

Comment: @Karsra If you willing to help me, do. otherwise don't post like this!

Comment: i have not any problem with you at all , but the reason that i say that actually is most useful for yourself ! because when you pot some even a bit of your code , you can get a better answer ! because nothing like a code cannot show what you want and when the users knows that what you want their answer are more helpful for you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bit long winded, but another approach.

```
d1 = datetime.strptime('08:10:32', '%H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.strptime('12:34:45', '%H:%M:%S')
time_delta = d2 - d1
float('.'.join(str(time_delta).split(":")[0:2]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
d1 = datetime.strptime('08:34:32', '%H:%M:%S')
d2 = datetime.strptime('12:34:32', '%H:%M:%S')
```

Now `d1.hour - d2.hour` gives hours difference and `d1.minute - d2.minute` gives minutes difference, use them to construct your wanted result.

Another useful library is [`Arrow`](http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/), try it.